# Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in php

Tags: php, shell

heey everyone i'm trying to create a folder for every user try to sign into my php app and i get that message [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NVx9.jpg)

and my php code is here

```
function createChatFolder($email) {
    if(!file_exists('../../conversation'.$email)){
        if(mkdir('../../conversation'.$email , 0777 ,true)){
            $myfile = fopen('/opt/lampp/htdocs/facebookMV/web/conversation/'.$email.'/status.xml', 'w+');
            if($myfile){
                $txt = '<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="utf-8"   ?>'.PHP_EOL.'<status>1</status>';
                fwrite($myfile, $txt);
                fclose($myfile);
            }else{
                echo 'there was an error while creating the status file';
            }
        }else{ 
            echo 'there was an error while creating thee '.$email.' folder ';
        }
    }
}
```

can any one tell me from where the problem is coming from 
NB : i'm using UBUNTU 14.04 and here is the mode of conversation folder

```
drwxr-xr-x 7 daemon daemon 4096 نوف 25 00:32 conversation
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `mkdir('../../conversation/'.$email , 0777 ,true)` since you wish to create subfolders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to change 
`if(!file_exists('../../conversation'.$email)){
    if(mkdir('../../conversation'.$email , 0777 ,true))`

to
`if(!file_exists('../../conversation/'.$email)){
   if(mkdir('../../conversation/'.$email , 0777 ,true))`

ie if you wish to create subfolders.

Then you  need to make sure that write permissions
are enabled for the user running the php, usually `www-data`.

If not sure, you could use the below command :

`ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'`

to determine which user apache is running as.

Using chmod to enable write permissions for all the users to a folder is dangerous.

So you could use setfacl command as root like below.

`setfacl -m u:www-data:w /path/to/conversation`

Comment: my user apache is daemon not www-data and he has all the permission to write in conversation but i;m still having the same error

Comment: you wish to create subfolders in conversation folder right? You are missing `/` in two places. By omitting the slashes you are trying to write  to `../../` folder for which `daemon` might not have the permission to write to.. please see my edit @RmidiAyoub

Comment: for example, if you consider this directory structure test1->test2->your_document_root and suppose that folder conversationis in the test1 directory, by `mkdir('../../conversation'.$email , 0777 ,true)` you are trying to create a new folder named `conversationsome@email.com` to the test1 directory for which the daemon user might not have permissioins. For `$myfile = fopen...` statement however you're putting the hashes correctly.